# Does firebase charge when downloading backup files?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

You can enable Firebase Realtime DB to be automatically backed up daily.

Do they charge when downloading data to backup? Or do they charge when we download a backup file (.zip file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backups of the Firebase Realtime Database are written to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. There is no bandwidth charge for the  writing of the backups to the bucket.

You will be charged for the storage space the backups occupy, and for downloading the backups from the bucket. Both are charged as a normal GCS operations.

Also see the [cost section of the documentation for the backup feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups?authuser=0#costs):

> The backups feature can be enabled for [Blaze](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0) projects for no additional cost. However, you will be charged at the [standard rates](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing?authuser=0) for the backup files placed in your Google Cloud Storage bucket. You can enable [Gzip Compression](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups?authuser=0#gzip_compression) and [Storage 30 day Lifecycle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups?authuser=0#storage_lifecycle) to reduce your storage costs.

Comment: You guys are really quick. Thank you very much for the quick response. :)